# A basic question on subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

The reason subspace was introduced that we want to concentrate on a reduced subset of a vector space for which still it is a vector space under those operations. Then there should be a notion of minimal subspace i.e. the subset which is a vector space but any proper subset of it is not a vector space. We should work on that minimal subset. Is there any such notion ?

Comment: The only minimal subspace is the one-element subspace consisting of the zero vector.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have any other conditions, you're probably looking for the zero (sub)space $\{0\}$. If $V$ is a vector space and you have a set of vectors $S\subseteq V$, you can talk about the subspace generated by $S$, which is the smallest subspace of $V$ containing $S$. Alternatively, it is the intersection of all subspaces containing $S$, or the set of all linear combinations drawn from $S$.

Comment: adding on: the set of all linear combinations of vectors drawn from $S$ is called the *linear span* of $S$

Answer (score 0):

let `A` is subset of `X` - vector space. Minimal vector subspace containing `A` is denoted as `Span(A)`.